# Getting videos directly into the Videos app

Tags: itunes, ipad

I often download videos from online courses on the Internet.

When I need to transfer them to the iPad, I have to connect them to a Windows or Mac running iTunes, and drop them in there.

Is there a way I could bypass connecting to the computer, and directly have the videos downloaded to the Videos app?

Answer (score 1):

No, not without jail breaking.

Answer (score 0):

There seems no way to download the movies in the Video application.
But I've seen Video uses the YouTube video database. So you can find out a way around. If you've jailbroken your iPad, you can use Cydia to install [YourTube HD](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-youtube-videos-on-ipad-with-yourtube-hd/) which will allow you do download movies directly onto your iPad.

If you don't which to jailbreak your iPad, you can install [TagDisk HD](http://www.ipadintouch.com/how-to-download-youtube-videos-to-your-ipad/).

Comment: Video doesn't have any YouTube support; I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: I just downloaded an app called 'Video' and it uses the YouTube library...

Comment: As the app every iOS device comes with to manage videos, movies, TV shows, and video podcasts is called Videos, it is assumed that when one is talking about an iOS app for managing videos that one is referring to Videos, not some third-party app. Actually, unless that's a jailbreak-only app, I don't see how Apple even let it on the App Store. They dont let third party apps have the same names as native apps or even other third-party apps.

Comment: @Timonthy is right, I'm talking about the in-built Videos app. Regarding the names, there's a little difference, the in-built one is "Videos", but the one Michiel downloaded is "Video" :)